# sound made while feeling cold

Tags: word-request, phrases, idioms

My grandmother makes noise like "sssshhhh" in very cold weather.

which word can I describe this activity/sound?

Thanks,

Comment: I think she is trembling (from the cold weather), and the sound she is making is hissing, which I'm not used to. (It's typically Brr...) However, I think she might be gasping or panting.

Answer (score 4):

Your grandmother is [shivering](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3ashivering&oq=define%3ashivering&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.4865j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8).  The word you are using is called an onomatopoeia, which is a word that is spelled in such a way as to make the sound.

Different cultures around the world make sounds differently.  See, for example, [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-linguistic_onomatopoeias).  Often, Americans will spell the sound "brr."  In Russia, I saw it spelled "zhzh" (actually it was in Cyrillic, but this is the English equivalent).

Comment: Thanks, @DamkerngT.  Aren't they fun?  When I've traveled and met new folks, comparing the way we vocalize sounds always seemed lighten the mood and lead to a stronger connection.

Comment: They're really fun. I also took an opportunity to update some Thai words there too. :)

Answer (score 3):

"Brrr!"

Pronunced "Burr, it's cold out!"

You can also roll the "rrr" if your flappy English speaking tongue can manage it!

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/brr

Answer (score 0):

What about "teeth chattering from cold"?